# Time delay of LED dimmer circuit problem

Tags: transistors, potentiometer, npn

I made a LED flip flop circuit using NPN transistor, it works pretty fine.
But my problem now is I don't know how to control the on and off time delay for the LEDs using potentiometer.
I tried putting it in the power source but when I adjust it to low it just reduces the LEDs brightness.
I need it that when I turn the potentiometer to the left (or opposite) direction the delay for the led on and off will be long and the LEDs will flip slowly, and when I switch the potentiometer to the right side, the on and off delay for the led will be short making the LEDs to flip faster.

Please anyone can help me.
Here is my circuit below
[image: led dimmer using NPN transistor]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want a slow flip-flop for flashing rather than a fast flip-flop for dimming.

The timing is determined by the 100 Ω / 10 μF capacitors which have a time constant, \$ \tau = RC = 100 \times 10 \times 10^{-6} = 0.001\ \text s \$. That means it will do about 500 cycles per second.

Normally you would change the R value to a larger value. Unfortunately your design is using the 100 Ω to control the LED current.

I think you need to redesign and separate the flip-flop from the LED drivers. You'll need at least two more transistors.